# What is the alternative to DistributedCache in MapReduce program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

It seems that DistributedCache comes in handy when you need to put a small amount of data that's going to be frequently used by your mapper/reducer to the the distributedCache. But in some circumstances, the data you want to put into your mapper, would be quite large, say over 300 MB. What would you do in such this cases ? What would be the alternative to distributedCache in such scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Distributed cache is several gigabytes by default, so 300MB is not necessarily a problem.  (You can adjust the size in `mapred-site.xml`.)  Getting 300MB to the node could still be worthwhile if your job runs frequently and there is little other churn in the cache.
2. The other option is to put your files on HDFS and have the tasks read them from there.  You can use the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` APIs to do that.

To pick which one is best, you should probably try it both ways and see what gives you better I/O and runtime numbers (including effects on other jobs).  It could depend on how frequently your job runs, how many other things are in the cache, map/reduce ratio and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Very insightful !

Comment: map-side join and reduce-side join can be alternative option if the file size is bigger than GB, I guess. please comment.